# Get Resource From Name in External Class

Tags: android

I have a string that identifies a resource that i want to grab.

I know about the following:

```
public int getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

However i need to use it in an external class, and it won't let me.

For example i have a string called "thefile" and i want to access R.raw.thefile

Any ideas? I'm stuck

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass a Context to your external class. Example...

```
public Myclass {

    public void doSomething (Context context) {
        int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(...);

}
```

Then in your Activity...

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.doSomething(this);
```

Comment: or he can just pass the context to the constructor of MyClass , and inside the method of doSomething () , he can use this.context 

and one more note : the method DoSomeThing() ==>doSomething() ; it's not a class ^^

Comment: @Houcine: Typo - I spend a lot of time coding C# where methods often start upper-case. And yes, depending on the number of MyClass's methods which need to use the Context it may be better to pass in the constructor and maintain a local reference.